# mysql fulltext search returning no records

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm not getting any rows returned with the following, and I don't know why. Have I defined the fulltext index correctly?

```
CREATE TABLE `client_contact` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `company` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billing_address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `client_search` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `company`, `billing_address`) VALUES
('John', 'Smith', 'john.smith@company.com', '123456', 1, '1 Any Street'),
('Mary', 'Smith', 'mary.smith@company.com', '123456', 1, '1 Any Street');


SELECT cl.*
FROM client_contact cl 
WHERE MATCH(cl.first_name, cl.last_name, cl.email) AGAINST ('Smith')
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d54b/1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the keyword `Smith` exists in all rows. [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) says "Words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match".

Comment: That's something new! :O Didn't know that :) Interesting. Thanks!